# Passing php var to javascript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps

I am trying to pass php $var to Javascript in google map script. I have address table in DB. And with controller I fetch it to view and now try to pass it in Javascript and iterate it.

But having some trouble I think my code a bit corrupted. By the way I dont have lat and lng, just addresses.

```
function initMap(){
        var options = {
            zoom:8,
            center:
            @foreach($address as $addr){
               {!! $addr->address !!} 
            }
            @endforeach
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:
                @foreach($address as $addr){
                   {!! $addr->address !!}
                }
                @endforeach
            map:map
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:'content here'
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        })

    }
```

And Map API calling

```
<script async defer
       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

*controller*

```
public function index()
{

    $address = DB::table("allestates")
        ->get();

    return view("home", compact('address'));

}
```

Address column in DB:

[image: addresses]

Comment: It looks like you are doing right however I think your problem might be that you are giving multiple lat & lng for the center which I believe should be a single location for the center of the map to to.

Comment: I update the code, check the question!. but still no map? @Josh

Comment: Can you please add the code that you get the $address variable from?

Comment: I added the controller, updated question. By the way I dont have lat lng in the database, just pure addresses @Josh

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but if you could please add the fields for the $address records that will allow me to give you a complete answer that should fix your problem

Comment: No bother, thank you. You mean, you want the see the addresses in DB, I updated the question. Could you check it out please. @Josh

Comment: sorry I mean can you please show the columns in the "allestate"table so that I know what data to get from the records?

Comment: I already the add the image of the column in the question. It's japanese though :) but addresses@Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few things that could be causing the issue

Try this:

```
function initMap(){
    var options = {
        zoom:8,
        center:
           '{!! $address[0]->address !!}'
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:
            @foreach($address as $addr)
               '{!! $addr->address !!}'
            @endforeach
        map:map
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:'content here'
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function () {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    })

}
```

So first of all the `@foreach (...)` does not use `{` or `}`

Second you want to output any information that is not only numeric inside of quotes

Hope this helps

Comment: ah, right that's my rookie mistake. Thanks a lot this solved the problem! By the way one last question. Do i need to use API key in like this {{env("api key")}} or just copy the key? like in the question?

Comment: I would use `{{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API') }}` as this will allow you to change the key in the future and update it everywhere that you use it. I would however make sure you limit the use of it as it will be public

Comment: hm, it's good idea. but in the .env file there is no google map api section. How to create it? sorry for the burden. Do i need to open another question for this? :)

Comment: just add `GOOGLE_MAPS_API={google maps api here}` and it will auto pick it up however it is probs better practice to do this through config files. Look here for details https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration